# Storing data on EC2 vs S3 in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm fairly new to AWS and am having trouble understanding what the best practice should be for hosting a product I'm developing...

I have a tool I plan on running on an EC2 instance but it only needs to run a couple of times a year, the rest of the time I can have the instance stopped and not incur charges.  However the product utilizes quite a bit of data (approx 15 - 25 GB depending on the run).  I understand that S3 is meant for storing data long term.  But is there any reason why I can't just leave the data on an EC2 (even when it's stopped).  Or do I have to do manual copies from S3 every time I want to execute a run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the instance is off, you are still incurring charges for the EBS volumes. S3 also has the advantage of being somewhat more durable.

It would probably be a good idea to back up your data or snapshot your volume to s3 as a precaution, but I would not worry about transferring data back and forth.

Comment: Obviously backing up the data on S3 is a good idea, but there is no downside/bad practice (outside of incurring EBS cost) to leaving the data on the EC2 instance?

Comment: In your case cost is the only reason. With larger jobs, often multiple instances are launched and not kept after processing is complete. In those cases its best to store data in s3.